# AngularJS with Rails 4.2 - how to make $routeProvider.when() work properly?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I am using Rails 4.2 with [angularjs-rails](https://github.com/hiravgandhi/angularjs-rails) and [angular-rails-templates](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) gems.  When I first go to the home page (index.html) and try and click to '#/kiteboards/{{kiteboard.id}}/users', the hashbang'd URL appears in the browser bar, e.g., 'http://localhost:3000/#/kiteboards/1/users', but the users.html.haml template (courtesy of angular-rails-templates) is not being loaded.

This should be a simple routing problem....Is it the AngularJS routing code that is wrong?  Or is it something else?  No JS error messages appear in the Chrome dev tools console, so it seems like AngularJS is wired up correctly, but maybe I am missing a "/" somewhere in the routing.

**AngularJS code snippet**

```
  var kiteApp = angular.module('kiteApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'templates']);
  kiteApp.controller('kiteCtr', ['$scope', 'KiteboardApi', kiteCtr]);
  kiteApp.factory('KiteboardApi', ['$resource', KiteboardApi]);
  kiteApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/kiteboards/:kiteboard_id/users', {
      templateUrl: 'users.html',
      resolve: {
        usersData: function(KiteboardAPI) {
          return KiteboardAPI.fetchUsers({ kiteboard_id: $route.current.params.kiteboard_id }).$promise.then(function(data) {
            return data;
          });
        }
      },
      controller: 'kiteCtr'
    })
  }]);
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ../templates

//= require_tree .
```

**In app/assets/templates/users.html.haml:**

```
%div#section{"ng-app"=>"kiteApp", "ng-controller"=>"kiteCtr"}
  %table
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Name
    %tbody
      %tr{"ng-repeat" => "user in usersData track by $index"}
        %td
```

**Home page, index.html, loaded by Rails**

```
%div{"ng-app"=>"kiteApp", "ng-controller"=>"kiteCtr"}
  %table
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Index #
        %th Name 
    %tbody
      %tr{"ng-repeat" => "kiteboard in kiteboards track by $index"}
        %td {{$index}}
        %td
          %a{href: '#/kiteboards/{{kiteboard.id}}/users'} {{kiteboard.name}}
```

Comment: you should inject `$route` in the resolve `usersData` function before passing that value to `$resource`: call .. it should be `usersData: function(KiteboardAPI, $route)` instead of `usersData: function(KiteboardAPI)`

Comment: As it turns out, this issue mainly had to do with a Sprockets 3 incompatibility with angular-rails-templates and not using the ng-view directive.